# dotnet core support for a risc-v computer

Tags: .net, riscv

as we know dotnet core is multi-platform, but I need to know if it supports risc-v processes/ computers?

I guess dotnet core supports ARM-64 but not sure if supports risc-v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ARM64, the answer is yes. I had deployed .NET 6/7 on my Raspberry pi following the guidance, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment. It worked very well. So, it is similar deployment on other ARM system. BTW, there are download links for ARM32/ARM64 on the official website, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0.

For RISC-V, the answer is not completed. They are doing this and there had been multiple PRs merged into main branch. It is OK to print "Hello World!" on RISC-V. You could track the process by issue thread, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36748.